# How is a submodule that contains a gem project have its resources required from a surrounding gem project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, require

This is something that's becoming a rather great frustration. I have two Ruby project repositories on GitHub. I'll call them Project A and Project B. I set up a bunch of Ruby scripts and such inside Project B and create a submodule of that project in Project A. When I try to require the resources from Project B in a simple Ruby class or something in Project A, I get thrown errors saying that it requires Project B's resources that are declared in its Gemfile. I run `bundle --path vendor/bundle` inside the local Project B directory, change back into Project A, and then run my server to be greeted w/ those same errors. What is the way of requiring Project B's resources w/out having to require its Gemfile dependencies in Project A?

Comment: It sounds like the gems from project B are being installed but aren't accessible in project A. Is the path that Project B's gems are being installed to in the load path of Project A?

Comment: Let's say I use `bundle --path vendor/bundle` on both projects. Project A's resources are on the path vendor/bundle, and submodule Project B has its own vendor/bundle on the path to the submodule. How are you referring in terms of a load path?

Comment: Sorry for confusion -- When ruby loads other files through require or load it looks in the ruby load path for the files it's trying to load. If it can't find the files it's looking for it will throw an error. It sounds like you may need to add project B's bundle path to the first projects load path. This link offers another description of what I'm talking about: http://gistflow.com/posts/443-ruby-load-paths